# It is possible to re-run a job in Google Cloud Dataflow after succeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Maybe the question sounds stupid but I was wondering if once the job is successfully finished and having ID, is it possible to start the same job again?
Or is it necessary to create another one?
Because otherwise I would have the job with the same name throughout the list.

I just want to know if there is a way to restart it without recreating it again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run the exact same job again, but you can create a new job with the same name that runs the same code.  It will just have a different job ID and show up as a separate entry in the job list.

If you want to make running repeated jobs easier, you can create a [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates).  This will let you create jobs from that template via a gcloud command instead of having to run your pipeline code.

Comment: Is it correct? I mean in dataflow job list i have multiple jobs with the same name that have the same scope. I was thinking that was a more efficient way to do it, like re-run a previous job

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to re-run a previous job; you just need to run a new one.  You can create a template and repeatedly create jobs from that template though.  I've edited my answer with info about that

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Dataflow does have a re-start function. [See SDK here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs). One suggested pattern (to help with deployment) is to create a template for the graph you want to repeatedly run AND execute the template.

Comment: I Created a function, template, that generate a pipeline, job, each time is triggered. My question is, is it possibile to run a job that I already created? Or is normal to have multiple jobs with the same scope